# Converting FILES to NTFS

Tags: linux, filesystems

I did something wrong with my dual-OS PC (XP Pro and Ubuntu) and it now only works when booting from an Ubuntu Live CD (8.04 LTS).

I am backing up my data to an external HDD for reinstalling everying.  I am not worried about the Linux part of my data because the external HDD is formatted in ext3, the file system Ubuntu operates on.

But what about the Windows part of my data?  Does Linux (the live CD) properly copy NTFS files into an ext3 HDD?  And then does Linux (this time, the newly installed Linux system on PC) properly copy them back to the NTFS partition?

I know I am asking a very simple question.  I am sorry if I appear to ask someone to do my homework but I cannot experiment myself now.

Thanks you all in advance!

Edit:
Is it perhaps better to format the external HDD in fat32?

Answer (score 1):

As amemus said, fat32 would be better for the external HDD. Even though it's Microsoft, fat32 is still, by far, the most supported HDD format.

That said, what you said SHOULD work, given you use a new-ish distro of linux with new packages.

Comment: I would use an Ubuntu 11.10 CD but my CD drive don't read it (or the CD is not properly burned, I don't know).  Still, I will be able to upgrade from 8.04 once it's installed in the system.  Do you think the latest LTS Ubuntu is new enough to handle NTFS more wisely?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 8.04 is very old these days, but I believe it had good support for NTFS read (using the old `ntfs` driver). It will correctly copy your Windows files to the ext3 external hard drive, plus or minus some attributes/permissions which have no equivalent in ext3.

Newer Ubuntu releases have full NTFS read/write support via the `ntfs-3g` driver which I have found to work very well.

Sidenote: I have found NTFS is a reasonably good filesystem for external hard drives - it works well for Windows and recent Linux computers, and it's technically superior to FAT32. The only issue is if you have to interact with Apple OSX, which still doesn't understand NTFS. (You can *make* OSX understand NTFS with a liberal application of FUSE and `ntfs-3g`, but it's not nice.)

*Note: This is probably the wrong Stack Exchange - StackOverflow is for programming questions. Maybe the Ubuntu stackexchange would have been better?*

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu shouldn't have a problem reading from NTFS.

Writing to NTFS used to be very difficult, but its gotten a lot better (a simple google search turns up [lots of results](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ubuntu+write+to+ntfs))

As long as you aren't working with large (~4GB) files, FAT32 will be easier to work with across lots of different platforms.